# volatile as argument identifier

Tags: c, pointers

I was asked a question in a recent interview there is a function defined below

```
int square(volatile int * p)
{
    return *p**p;
}
```

I was told that there is some thing wrong is this function and is not good for computing square, I think this is due to volatile, Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Because `volatile` suggests that `*p` may change partway through the evaluation of `*p * *p`. Especially on an embedded device where `p` could be any sort of weird thing, e.g. a pointer to some memory where some hardware directly stores and constantly updates the current value of a counter or something, or some exotic thing that say, changes its value every time you read it, or whatever, the sky is really the limit there.

Comment: So is it normal practice to define for example pointer like `p` in this case to be volatile, what would be the advantage and disadvantage of doing so

Comment: No, the best way would be as Kerrek SB's answer mentions; no pointer here, no `volatile` anything, just `int square (int)` and let the caller do the right thing (such as `square(*p)`) for the given situation. Also don't think of `volatile` as a thing with "advantages" and "disadvantages", it's just a tool for a job: Use it when you need it and be aware of what it implies.

Comment: Normal would be to not have any pointer involved in this function at all...

Comment: I told the same that it would just simpler to write as @Kerrek SB said, but they said it would multiply the pointed value to itself but is not suitable to calculate square, and the function is a valid function syntax wise

Comment: @Uint32 You do it like `int square (int v) { return v * v; }`, *not* `int square (int *p) { return p * p; }`, which doesn't make any sense. And yes the example they gave you is syntactically valid, it's just not functionally (or even semantically, really) correct.

Comment: Understanding the [use of volatile](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword) is critical to the correct functioning of code accessing hardware or sharing data across thread and interrupt contexts, which is why you were asked the question in interview.  Unless they were planning on taking on a trainee, it is critical that you understand such stuff if you call yourself an embedded systems developer.  I have used similar questions to quickly filter out weak candidates, and make the previous link required reading for trainees.

Comment: Thank you @Clifford for sharing the link It would be great if you could suggest some good books or a website for essentials and good programming practice for embedded systems.

Comment: @Uint32 Lots of good articles on the topic can be found here: http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Articles

Comment: @Uint32 : What Lundin said - many of Micheal Barr's articles appear on Embedded.com in any case.  You could fill shelves with books on various aspects of embedded systems development.  For a general comprehensive coverage consider *Embedded Software: The Works* by Colin Walls - also the author on many articles on Embedded,com and other publications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be an assumption that because `*p` is a volatile access, its value may differ during every evaluation, and thus you should only evaluate it once:

```
int q = *p;
return q * q;
```

That's of course silly design; the function should really be `int square(int)` and *the caller* should say `square(*p)`.